# Is it possible to create an index on a list within a postgres jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgres table with a jsonb column that contains a list we want to query against. The jsonb column data looks like this:

```
{"org": 3, "subscriberCodes": ["A555", "A666"]}
```

I'd like to be able to query against the table to search by subscriber code.

I know I can do a like query:

```
SELECT *
FROM permissions.application_settings
WHERE configuration->>'subscriberCodes' LIKE '%A555%'
```

But this has a couple of problems, I'd have to fire a query per subscriber code (I tried to figure out how to do an WHERE IN clause, but couldn't quite figure it out), and it ends up doing a sequential scan of the entire table (which would not be great for the number of records we have).

I'm not great with jsonb just yet. Is there a way of doing a WHERE IN clause and maybe creating an index on the array of subscriber codes so it doesn't require a sequential scan??

Comment: An indication that you are doing things wrong. Put the data in a defined table instead of hiding it in JSON.

Comment: You might have a better time working with a normalised structure, as Adrian Klaver suggested. If you can't alter it, [`jsonb` is indexable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) which can speed things up. To check for presence of values inside a `jsonb`, there's a [`jsonpath` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) `WHERE jsonb_path_exists(configuration,'$.subscriberCodes[*]?(@=="A555")`. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/uIN-TJuT)

Comment: Yeah if we had the option of working with a normalized structure that would def be ideal, but we're building into an existing one. I'll give the json_path_exists Approach and read up on indexing link you posted @Zegarek. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to know how you plan to query the column, [which functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) you'll be using and what subscripts are targeted the most - this helps [select an adequate index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). You can start with indexing the whole thing for use with [`jsonpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iSS_-g_m)

```sql
create index on permissions.application_settings using gin (jsonb_path_ops);

select * from permissions.application_settings
where configuration @? '$.subscriberCodes[*]?(@=="A555")';
```

An [expression/functional index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) can limit the index to a subscript:

```sql
create index on permissions.application_settings 
  using gin ((configuration->'subscriberCodes') jsonb_path_ops);

select * from permissions.application_settings
where configuration->'subscriberCodes' @? '$[*]?(@=="A555")';
```

You can also stick with [non-jsonpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) methods:

```sql
create index on permissions.application_settings 
  using gin ((configuration->'subscriberCodes') jsonb_ops);

select * from permissions.application_settings
where configuration->'subscriberCodes' ? 'A555';
```

Comment: Wow holy cow that was a fantastic explanation! TBH we don't have an exact plan for querying yet, we were just talking through options on using the existing schema vs building out a new table with a preference with figuring out how to use what's already there. Your answer gives us tons of perspective and options. Thanks for the help!!